# Flex SDK missing fundamental things

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flexbuilder, flash-builder

[alt text http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/4107/flashbuildershite.jpg](http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/4107/flashbuildershite.jpg)

All of a sudden Flash Builder 4 is missing all kinds of fundamental things and is generating incorrect errors. I've had the same issue yesterday, where I fixed it by downloading a new Flex SDK and importing that into FB. I did this again, but this time it fixed nothing.

I don't think it's something I did, like removing critical references from the build path. The errors also appeared on projects I was not working on at the time. It occurs for ActionScript, Flex and Flex Library projects alike.

---

Update 3: Well, i've singled the problem down to a single piece of code, though a very simple one. I can make a new workspace in FB and things work ok, then screw the workspace up forever by adding this code to a project. All projects will have errors and closing or even removing the faulty project does not change this. Making another new workspace (without the faulty code) makes my projects compile again.

Link: http://www.the3rdage.net/files/2745/Main.as
(i've uploaded the file in case an odd character or encoding error causes the error)

---

Update 2: I've tried manual compiling with mxmlc, the same errors occur. It appears to be an SDK problem, not Flash Builder.

---

Update: I find this stack trace in the Flash Builder error log:

```
!ENTRY com.adobe.flexbuilder.project 4 43 2010-05-11 11:55:47.495
!MESSAGE Uncaught exception in compiler
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at macromedia.asc.semantics.ConstantEvaluator.evaluate(ConstantEvaluator.java:2592)
    at macromedia.asc.parser.VariableBindingNode.evaluate(VariableBindingNode.java:64)
    at macromedia.asc.semantics.ConstantEvaluator.evaluate(ConstantEvaluator.java:2233)
    at macromedia.asc.parser.ListNode.evaluate(ListNode.java:44)
    at macromedia.asc.semantics.ConstantEvaluator.evaluate(ConstantEvaluator.java:2578)
    at macromedia.asc.parser.VariableDefinitionNode.evaluate(VariableDefinitionNode.java:48)
    at macromedia.asc.semantics.ConstantEvaluator.evaluate(ConstantEvaluator.java:2310)
    at macromedia.asc.parser.StatementListNode.evaluate(StatementListNode.java:60)
    at macromedia.asc.semantics.ConstantEvaluator.evaluate(ConstantEvaluator.java:2503)
    at macromedia.asc.parser.WithStatementNode.evaluate(WithStatementNode.java:44)
    at macromedia.asc.semantics.ConstantEvaluator.evaluate(ConstantEvaluator.java:2310)
    at macromedia.asc.parser.StatementListNode.evaluate(StatementListNode.java:60)
    at macromedia.asc.semantics.ConstantEvaluator.evaluate(ConstantEvaluator.java:2891)
    at macromedia.asc.parser.FunctionCommonNode.evaluate(FunctionCommonNode.java:106)
    at macromedia.asc.semantics.ConstantEvaluator.evaluate(ConstantEvaluator.java:2905)
    at macromedia.asc.parser.FunctionCommonNode.evaluate(FunctionCommonNode.java:106)
    at macromedia.asc.semantics.ConstantEvaluator.evaluate(ConstantEvaluator.java:3643)
    at macromedia.asc.parser.ClassDefinitionNode.evaluate(ClassDefinitionNode.java:106)
    at macromedia.asc.semantics.ConstantEvaluator.evaluate(ConstantEvaluator.java:3371)
    at macromedia.asc.parser.ProgramNode.evaluate(ProgramNode.java:80)
    at flex2.compiler.as3.As3Compiler.analyze4(As3Compiler.java:709)
    at flex2.compiler.CompilerAPI.analyze(CompilerAPI.java:3089)
    at flex2.compiler.CompilerAPI.analyze(CompilerAPI.java:2977)
    at flex2.compiler.CompilerAPI.batch2(CompilerAPI.java:528)
    at flex2.compiler.CompilerAPI.batch(CompilerAPI.java:1274)
    at flex2.compiler.CompilerAPI.compile(CompilerAPI.java:1496)
    at flex2.tools.oem.Application.compile(Application.java:1188)
    at flex2.tools.oem.Application.recompile(Application.java:1133)
    at flex2.tools.oem.Application.compile(Application.java:819)
    at flex2.tools.flexbuilder.BuilderApplication.compile(BuilderApplication.java:344)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.compiler.internal.ASApplicationBuilder$MyBuilder.mybuild(ASApplicationBuilder.java:276)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.compiler.internal.ASApplicationBuilder.build(ASApplicationBuilder.java:127)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.compiler.internal.ASBuilder.build(ASBuilder.java:190)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.compiler.internal.ASItemBuilder.build(ASItemBuilder.java:74)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexProjectBuilder.buildItem(FlexProjectBuilder.java:480)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexProjectBuilder.build(FlexProjectBuilder.java:306)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexIncrementalBuilder.build(FlexIncrementalBuilder.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Did you get this error previously or its all of sudden. Thanks for notifying the issue. Does it happen to you alone or your team too.

Comment: I've singled it down to a piece of code. See update 3

Comment: You should file a bug: http://bugs.adobe.com

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a chance to list this issue in their bugs list. I have not yet tried Flex 4. did you try to refresh your project and re open your flash builder.

Update:

What about a simple project. I think you are trying to load something which its not able to get.

```
mxmlc - verify-digests
```

Try this.

Comment: I've added the -verify-digests=true parameter, but the output is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Problems I've had that were somewhat similar, once I had FB running under the wrong version of Java. Another time I had done some edits to the flex-config.xml file in order to make it work with a Maven plugin we had written in house. After that we made the plugin look at a copy of the original xml file, so that problem went away.
hth.

Answer (score 0):

Might i recommend HFCD? The HellFire Compile Daemon is an out of process flex compiler that speeds up compile times immensely, and almost more importantly runs in a separate process from FlashBuidler. I have had some absolutely horrendous errors with Flash Builder due to the complexity and size of our project, where HFCD has helped tremendously here.